# How To Create A Wordpress Menu From Existing HTML Template Code?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have been using a HTML template for a website, and added Wordpress functionality. However, my navigation within Header.php just uses get_permalink for page links. I want to keep the same navigation menu with all it's functionality, but allow pages to be added within the dashboard.

The current code is as follows:

```
    <!-- Overlay Navigation Menu -->
<div class="overlay-navigation-wrapper enter-bottom" data-no-scrollbar data-animation="slide-in">
    <div class="overlay-navigation-scroll-pane">
        <div class="overlay-navigation-inner">
            <div class="v-align-middle">
                <div class="overlay-navigation-header row collapse full-width">
                    <div class="column width-12">
                        <div class="navigation-hide overlay-nav-hide">
                            <a href="#"> <span class="icon-cancel"></span> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row collapse full-width">
                    <div class="column width-12">
                        <nav class="overlay-navigation nav-block">
                            <h4 class="menu-title">Website Title</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Home' ) ) ?>">Home</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'About' ) ) ?>">About</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Services' ) ) ?>">Treatments &amp; Offers</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Shop' ) ) ?>">Store</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Contact' ) ) ?>">Contact</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Overlay Navigation Menu End -->
<div class="wrapper reveal-side-navigation">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="header header-bottom header-fixed-on-mobile header-transparent" data-sticky-threshold="window-height" data-bkg-threshold="100">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <div class="row nav-bar">
                    <div class="column width-12 nav-bar-inner">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <div class="logo-inner"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Home' ) ) ?>"><img src="" alt="Sartre Logo" /></a> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Home' ) ) ?>"><img src="" alt="Sartre Logo" /></a> </div>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block secondary-navigation nav-right">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="v-align-middle"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Contact' ) ) ?>" class="button small text-uppercase pull-right no-margin-bottom">Book Now </span></a> </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="aux-navigation hide">
                                    <!-- Aux Navigation -->
                                    <a href="#" class="navigation-show overlay-nav-show nav-icon"> <span class="icon-menu"></span> </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block primary-navigation nav-center">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Home' ) ) ?>">Home</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'About' ) ) ?>">About</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Services' ) ) ?>">Treatments &amp; Offers</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Shop' ) ) ?>">Store</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Contact' ) ) ?>">Contact</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header End -->
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is quite bloated, but allows for the mobile responsiveness and other Javascript effects that come with the theme.

What's the best way to approach this? Thanks

Comment: `using a HTML template for a website, and added WordPress functionality` can you please explain? did you created a separate html template for your page?

Comment: As in I've used a HTML/CSS template, and made it into a basic Wordpress Custom Theme. But it lacks the Nav functionality outlined above...

Comment: if you've used any theme, why don't you just call `<?php get_header() ?>` instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Register a navigation menu in your functions.php

```
<?php
function my_wp_nav_menu(){
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => 'Main Navigation'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_wp_nav_menu' );
```

Step 2: Go into *Appearance->Menus* in your Dashboard, add your navigation items, and select *Main Navigation* as the menu.

Step 3: Replace the navigation's `ul`s in your HTML with:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container' => '',
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
) );
```

This will replace your list with a WordPress menu that you can control in WordPress. By default, `wp_nav_menu` wraps the menu list with a `div` which is why we set `'container' => ''` so all you get is the menu list markup.

Comment: Glad I could help!